# Using the "*" or "|" symbol in ggplot2 annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put the following equation into a ggplot in R using the `annotate()` function.

[image: equation]

The closest I seem to be able to get so far is the following

```
ggplot()+ annotate("label", x = 1, y = 1, label = "APC == 0.50 ~ Depth ^ {-0.99} * (Cone == 0~Net == 1) ^ {0.59}", parse = TRUE, size = 5)
```

[image: ok annotation]

Which is fine, but it would be nice to be able to add the `*` and `|` symbols from the equation. I tried the following:

```
ggplot()+ annotate("label", x = 1, y = 1, label = "APC == 0.50 * Depth ^ {-0.99} * (Cone == 0|Net == 1) ^ {0.59}", parse = TRUE, size = 5)
```

but it just ends up looking weird

[image: strange looking annotation]

Any advice about how I can get the or and star symbols added?

Also imaginary bonus points if somebody can explain to me what actually is happening with the `|` symbol when I try to use it, why does it appear where it does and add parentheses and a comma?

Comment: In general, documentation for this is at `?plotmath`, with `demo(plotmath)` being especially helpful. That shows to use `%*%` for the multiplication, but I couldn't work out anything for `|` based on what's there and am very impressed by the `latex2exp` answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative might be to use LaTeX expressions through `latex2exp::TeX`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
ggplot() +
    annotate(
        "label",
        x = 1, y = 1,
        label = TeX("$APC = 0.50 \\times Depth^{-0.99} \\times (Cone = 0 | Net = 1)^{0.59}$"),
        size = 5)
```

[image]

Two additional comments:

1. It is perhaps important to point out that `latex2exp` supports *some* LaTeX expressions but not all. For example, in LaTeX `\vert` and `|` are synonymous, but while `latex2exp` correctly typesets `|` it fails for `\vert`. The [`latex2exp` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html) has a section "Supported LaTeX" that contains a list of supported LaTeX expressions.
2. All LaTeX commands in `latex2exp::TeX` need to be prefixed (escaped) with an additional backslash. So `\times` becomes `\\times`.